# how to call php file in ajax function?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, magento-1.7

I've got this problem that I can't solve. Partly because I can't explain it with the right terms. I'm new to this so sorry for this clumsy question.

Below you can see an overview of my goal.I tried to get all category id's in a dynamic dropdown list ,the second dropdown list is based on the first dropdown list selection for this i find some code its working fine in local but i tried inside magento its not working Why ?

Here is my code

```
<tr>
                <td class="tdpadfirst">
                <label for="category" class="rightgap"><?php echo Mage::helper('marketplacepartner')->__('Product Category') ?>:</label>
                <span class="required starimp">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                    </td>

                <td class="tdpadfirst">
                <select id="category" class="myinput-text required-entry widthinput" name="category" onChange="updateCategory(this.value)">
                <option value="">--Select Categories--</option>
                <?php
                include('db.php');
                $sql=mysql_query("select entity_id from catalog_category_entity where level='2';");
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                $id=$row['entity_id'];
                $data=$row['parent_id'];?>
                <!--echo '<option value="'.$entity_id.'">'.$parent_id.'</option>';-->
                <option value="<?php echo $id ?>"><?php echo $id ?></option>
                <?php  } ?>
                </select>
                <select name="city" class="city">
                <option selected="selected">--Select subcategory--</option>
                </select></td></tr>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/
ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".country").change(function() {
    var id=$(this).val();
    var dataString = 'id='+ id;
    $.ajax ({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_city.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html) {
       $(".city").html(html);
    }
    });
});
});
```

ajax_city.php is :

```
   <?php
include('db.php');
if($_POST['id']) {
   $id=$_POST['id'];
    $sql=mysql_query("select entity_id from catalog_category_entity where parent_id='$id'");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $id=$row['entity_id'];
        $data=$row['parent_id'];
        echo '<option value="'.$data.'">'.$id.'</option>';
    }
}
```

?>

And db.php is :

```
   <?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "admin";
$mysql_database = "magento16";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) 
or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
```

?>

Comment: Just check the path is correct. What error you are getting.?

Answer (score 0):

Could use specify what you mean by "its working fine in local but i tried inside magento its not working?"

I'm not 100% sure if you have done this based on your question. Try replacing the php code in ajax_city.php with just html you might be able to isolate the issue.

You may need to allow the cross domian access depending on your setup. Try adding this code to your ajax_city.php page.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
```

On an unrelated note, the way you have written your ajax_city.php file you have left yourself vulnerable to SQL injection. Assuming your "$id" value in your sql is supposed to be an integer you can simply force the typecasting to prevent the sql injection.

```
...entity_id from catalog_category_entity where parent_id='$id'");
```

Change:

```
$id=$_POST['id'];
```

To:

$id=intval($_POST['id']);

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your response .. I have a table with the name : catalog_category_entity   And in that i have three columns (entity_id,parent_id,level)

Comment: yeah .. i tried this out side magento its working fine And Now i just copied that code inside magento here its not working why  ?

Comment: still i have the same issue any one can help me please

Comment: Hey Jhon if you post the entire source I would be happy to take a closer look at it. I cannot identify the problem from what you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the path to ajax file is correct, the way i see magento has a base .htaccess. Check if the ajax file you are calling is actually being called by checking NET requests sent in your browser, probably using firebug in firefox or chromes default debugger.
If its working fine outside magento and path to file is still correct and data is not showing up try making up a simple module in magento by using mage::catalog_category Model. I hope it may help.. :)

Comment: yeah your right @Sarthak Sawhney  my problem is the ajax file is not sending the requests to the browser... i need help about this upto  now i tried for this but no use

Comment: How can i make a mage::catalog_category model ?

Comment: Hi,
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(X);
Use catalog model to load the category you want to, next use addfieldtofilter to apply filters.
make this file in app/frontend/../catalog/category/ folder (by .. i mean the path to your theme directory.) 

http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/

Use this link above to create yourself a module fast. Now put the code in your frontend file and you will a have a url to return you the data you expect. Simply use this url for calling ajax from the page you want. 

OR

you can edit .htaccess in root to allow access to the files that exist.

Comment: Sorry for late replying.. :)